# the approach to restore a pre-configured docker image

Tags: docker, repository, backup, restore, snapshot

I am completely new to docker. I have a quick question about docker images.

Assume that I have setup a local docker image with certain software / server installed. So now I would need to set a checkpoint / snapshot here, then all the work done after this checkpoint is temporary; which means at a certain time, I would restore the original image (from that checkpoint) and overwrite everything in the temporary image.

My first question is if the above use-case make sense?
My second question, if the above make sense, what is the approach in doing that checkpoint (simply how, as I am keeping the checkpoint image in local diskspace only, no cloud repos involved) and how to restore the images to overwrite everything in the temporary image when needed.

Though I have read a bit of docker documentation, but am still struggling in the conceptual things.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense even though you could consider [managing data in container or volume (or host folder mounted in the container)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/).
That way the data remains persistent even when you stop and restart the container.

> what is the approach in doing that checkpoint

If your container does not mount a volume, and has its data inside, then yes, stopping and removing a container will lose that data.

One possibility is to create that snapshot with [`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/).
That will freeze the container state as a new image, that you can run later.

Example:

```
$ docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS              NAMES
c3f279d17e0a        ubuntu:12.04        /bin/bash           7 days ago          Up 25 hours                            desperate_dubinsky
197387f1b436        ubuntu:12.04        /bin/bash           7 days ago          Up 25 hours                            focused_hamilton

$ docker commit c3f279d17e0a  svendowideit/testimage:version3

f5283438590d

$ docker images

REPOSITORY                        TAG                 ID                  CREATED             SIZE
svendowideit/testimage            version3            f5283438590d        16 seconds ago      335.7 MB
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is **nothing like checkpoint or so with respect to Docker.** But you can save the actions performed on the container as Images to create a new Image.

Giving an **example to have better understanding**:

Lets run a container using an base Ubuntu Image and create a folder inside the container:

```
#docker run -it ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
root@58246867493d:/# 
root@58246867493d:/# cd /root
root@58246867493d:~# ls
root@58246867493d:~# mkdir TEST_DIR
root@58246867493d:~# exit
```

**Status of the exited container:**

```
# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                        PORTS               NAMES
58246867493d        ubuntu:14.04        "/bin/bash"         2 minutes ago       Exited (127) 57 seconds ago                       hungry_turing
```

**Now you can commit the changes so that the container will be saved into a new Docker Image:**

```
#docker commit 58246867493d ubuntu:15.0
```

Get docker Images

```
# docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
**ubuntu              15.0                acac1f3733b2        10 seconds ago      188MB**
ubuntu              14.04               132b7427a3b4        10 hours ago        188MB
```

Run the **newly build Image to see the changes committed in the previous container.**

```
# docker run -it ubuntu:15.0 /bin/bash
root@3a48af5eaec9:/# cd /root/
root@3a48af5eaec9:~# ls
TEST_DIR
root@3a48af5eaec9:~# exit
```

As you have asked, **any further changes you do on this container either can be committed to form a new Image or can be ignored** .

Hope it helps.